# iptables gets huge because of fail2ban

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

fail2ban is filling my iptables even though it is releasing banned IPs after a certain time. It seems that attacks are very frequent on my server. As a result, my iptables is getting huge. Is there any issue if iptables contains 5000 entries or more? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I reduced the bantime recidive filter from the previous value (1 week) to 1 day. Now iptables entries are recycled everyday.